# How to restart a substrate node

Tags: rust, blockchain, substrate, parity, polkadot

I'm confused, how do I restart a substrate node? I use `ctrl c` in the terminal window where the node is running to stop it and then I write the commands which I used to run the node in the first place, is that the way to restart the nodes?

Comment: Correct - this is how you restart a node.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is right for hot reload in development mode, but still you can make a service from systemd by echo the service like this sample [script](https://github.com/selendra/indracore/blob/main/scripts/create_service.sh)

Comment: Is it the same case when updating/upgrading a running substrate node? 
Like, if you want to add a new subcommand...
Do I have to terminate the running node, and start/run a new version of it?

Comment: you can dockerize commands and run docker that will works